# custom post creation on front page - on submit a search is done

Tags: custom-post-types, pages, homepage

Using a child theme of WP 2013 theme...

In Settings > Reading, 'Front page displays' 
I have selected 'static page' and assigned it a page titled Home. 
For that page, I've assigned a custom template.

That template calls a custom shortcode that displays a form for creating a custom post. 
And a loop to show the 10 most recent post of that cpt.

Everything works fine - except that on submit, it refreshes to the archive page for the category assigned when creating the custom post.

So it searches for that category.

If I call the same shortcode on a different page, such as Contact, that isn't a front page, then on submit it will refresh to that page.

Why does it search for the category when submitted from the front page?
And how can I stop it?

Comment: paste your shortcode function here, so we can investigate why?

Comment: shortcode function added.  If I use wp_terms_checklist, it refreshes to home page.  But wp_dropdown_categories() or get_categories refreshes to archive page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `the_permalink();` in form action value, to submit the form data.

```
<form id="fep-new-dog" name="new_dog" method="post" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Pretty obvious once I see your answer, lol.  Also got it working with a htaccess 301